# How do I set the RUST_TEST_TASKS environment variable?

Tags: testing, rust

I am attempting to write tests for my Rust program. Normally, these tests are run in parallel but I want to run them sequentially. I looked around and I can set this environment variable `RUST_TEST_TASKS=1`, but I am not sure where to do that.

Answer (score 4):

The environment variable is actually `RUST_TEST_THREADS`

Answer (score 2):

I think what they mean is setting the environment variables in the shell the test runner is running in, such as:

```
RUST_TEST_TASKS=1 ./my-test-runner
```

or exporting it:

```
export RUST_TEST_TASKS=1
./my-test-runner
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the solution. I tried it and I can still see the output as a result of running the tests in parallel. I think it might have to do with https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.set_var.html but I am not sure where to  call it. I am also using `cargo test` to run my tests.

Comment: I don't think that is actually different from setting it in the shell... Can you compose an example as a gist, maybe?